# Where to find animated matrix transformations in an fbx file?

Tags: animation, transformation, fbx

Where can I find matrix transformation animation data in an fbx file?

I have an fbx file with animations. I have successfully read the indices, matrix, and weight from it.

How can I get the frame-by-frame changes in the matrix? Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the answer in the Autodesk documentation.

Comment: blender has an (open-source) addon that imports fbx files, written in python. you can look at how they do it there, it may be complex, but it does the job. it's in the folder blender-2.80\2.80\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx

Comment: @darius thanks, I'll take a look